# My Class in SQLAlchemy has a boolean field that always returns True

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using MySQL with SQLAlchemy. I have a class defined like so:

```
Base = sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base()
class process(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'processes'
    process = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    get_javascript = sqlalchemy.Column(sqlalchemy.types.Boolean, nullable=False)
```

With my schema defined like so:

```
CREATE TABLE processes
(
  process Mediumint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  get_javascript Varchar(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (process)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

In my database, I have the following rows:

```
+---------+----------------+
| process | get_javascript |
+---------+----------------+
|      17 | 0              |
|      18 | 1              |
+---------+----------------+
```

Querying them in Python always gives me true for the `get_javascript` field.

```
>>> for i in s.query(db_classes.process).all():
...     print i.process, i.get_javascript
... 
17 True
18 True
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, SQLAlchemy doesn't like it when you use `VarChar(1)` for a boolean field. Switched it to `BOOLEAN` and recreated the database. It worked.

Comment: You should look at using `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` to have SQLAlchemy create the schemas for you